# Spring-Boot + Thymeleaf, carregar dados em janela modal do Bootstrap

Tags: java, postgresql, bootstrap, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Boa tarde!
Estou utilizando o spring-boot e thymeleaf para desenvolver uma aplicação java, gostaria de saber como posso fazer pra carregar registros pra janela modal do bootstrap ao clicar no link da tabela que lista os registros.

Exemplo: Na tela de consulta de usuários, eu tenho 3 botões visualizar, editar, excluir. O botão visualizar só irá carregar os dados do usuário selecionado na janela modal, não permitindo a edição. O botão editar, fará a mesma coisa, mas permitirá o usuário editar os dados pelo form. Qual a melhor maneira de fazer isso? Agradeço qualquer ajuda, estou começando agora e estou um pouco perdido. Abraços!

Answer (score 1):

se vc estiver usando `bootstrap` existe um evento chamado `show.bs.modal`, ele é disparado toda vez q um modal aparece, da pra vc construir algo dentro do seu modal ao clicar nos botões de sua tabela.

vc pode fazer um `javascript` assim

```
$("SeuModal").on("show.bs.modal",function(){
    //coloque seu codigo aqui

});
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, mas eu resolvi isso já tem uns meses e esqueci de atualizar aqui. hahaha

Answer (score 0):

Qual foi a solução?
Eu tenho um cadastro de ordem de serviço e preciso adicionar o cliente, quando clicar na
lupa eu preciso abrir um modal com uma lista de clientes, e clica em um botão e adicionar esse cliente no meu formulário
Então no meu form ficaria assim:
Cliente:Maria da Silva

Comment: Olá Ludmylla, infelizmente eu não possuo mais o código desse projeto, foi um dos primeiros que fiz no estágio em 2017. Mas no seu caso, acredito que seria criar o formulário normalmente dentro da modal utilizando o thymeleaf e ao selecionar o Cliente na lista, vc usa a função th:onchange para pegar um objeto com a informação completa do cliente e no action do form vc chama o endpoint/método do seu controller que vai criar o usuário. Desculpe se isso não ajuda muito, tem muito tempo que não trabalho com essa tecnologia.

Comment: Vê se esse vídeo te ajuda https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8c0OYbtfGa8